# Set anaconda variable

Tags: python, anaconda

I've set up my environmental variables to launch anaconda from the command window in windows, however seems that I'm doing something wrong.

I added `C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts;` to my path, but when I type `python` I just get

```
T:\>python
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 19 2016, 13:29:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org

T:\>
```

Anaconda is launched then it exits right away. Why is this happening?

Here is the conda info

```
Current conda install:

           platform : win-64
      conda version : 4.3.7
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.7
conda-build version : 1.8.2
     python version : 2.7.13.final.0
   requests version : 2.12.4
   root environment : C:\Anaconda  (writable)
default environment : C:\Anaconda
   envs directories : C:\Anaconda\envs
      package cache : C:\Anaconda\pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/msys2/noarch
        config file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.7 requests/2.12.4 CPython/2.7.13 Windows/8.1 Windows/6.3.9600
```

Comment: what's the output of `conda info`?

Comment: @PaulH i edited the question to include the info

Answer (score 0):

Install Anaconda and don't change the default settings. Everything will work as expected. `C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Anaconda3\condabin` will be added to your PATH and you'll only need to `conda activate` (or run the Anaconda-Prompt shortcut) to start using Python. Adding `C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts;` manually to the PATH simply isn't good enough.